# BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) when trying to close a Display in X11

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, x11, xlib

I am writing in x86-64 NASM assembly and I wrote a function to close a window using X11 on Ubuntu via WSL

I keep getting this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  18 (X_ChangeProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0xe002a0
  Serial number of failed request:  8
  Current serial number in output stream:  18
```

my code looks like this:

```
section .bss
    Ox:     resd 1
    Oy:     resd 1
    null:   resq 1
    dis:    resq 1             ;pointer to dis
    screen: resq 1
    gc:     resq 1

    black:  resq 1
    white:  resq 1
    red:    resq 1
    blue:   resq 1
    win:    resq 21
    event:  resb 0x60

    
section .text
extern  printf, exit
extern  XOpenDisplay, XCreateSimpleWindow, XSetStandardProperties, XSelectInput, XCreateGC, XSetBackground, XSetForeground, XClearWindow, XMapRaised, XFreeGC, XDestroyWindow, XCloseDisplay, XNextEvent

global main
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp

    call    init

    call    closeWin

    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret

init:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp

    mov     dword [Ox], 100
    mov     dword [Oy], 100
    mov     qword [black], 0x000000
    mov     qword [white], 0xffffff
    mov     qword [red], 0xff0000
    mov     qword [blue], 0x0000ff

    lea     rdi, 0
    call    XOpenDisplay
    mov     qword [dis], rax

    mov     rax, [dis+0xe0]
    mov     qword [screen], rax


    mov     rax, [dis]
    mov     rdx, [rax +0xe8]
    mov     rax, [dis]
    mov     eax, [rax + 0xe0]
    cdqe
    shl     rax, 7
    add     rax, rdx
    mov     rax, [rax + 0x10]
    
    mov     rdi, [dis]
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     rdx, 0
    mov     rcx, 0
    mov     r8, 300
    mov     r9, 300

    mov     rax, [black]
    push    rax
    mov     rax, [white]
    push    rax
    mov     rax, 5
    push    rax
    call    XCreateSimpleWindow
    mov     [win], rax    
    add     rsp, 24



    mov     rdi, [dis]
    mov     rsi, [dis]
    mov     rax, "Title"
    push    rax
    mov     rax, "Hi"
    push    rax
    lea     rdx, [rbp-8]
    lea     rcx, [rbp-16]
    mov     r8, 0
    mov     r9, 0x0
    push    r8
    push    r9
    call    XSetStandardProperties
    add     rsp, 0x20


    mov     rdi, [dis]
    mov     rsi, [win]
    mov     rdx, ExposureMask
    mov     rax, ButtonPressMask
    or      rdx, rax
    mov     rax, KeyPressMask
    or      rdx, rax
    call    XSelectInput

    mov     rdi, [dis]
    mov     rsi, [win]
    xor     rdx, rdx
    xor     rcx, rcx
    call    XCreateGC
    mov     [gc], rax

    mov     rdi, [dis]
    mov     rsi, [gc]
    mov     rdx, [white]
    call    XSetBackground

    mov     rdi, [dis]
    mov     rsi, [gc]
    mov     rdx, [black]
    call    XSetForeground

    mov     rdi, [dis]
    mov     rsi, [win]
    call    XClearWindow

    mov     rdi, [dis]
    mov     rsi, [win]
    call    XMapRaised


    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret

closeWin:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp

    mov     rdi, [dis]
    mov     rsi, [gc]
    call    XFreeGC

    mov     rdi, [dis]
    mov     rsi, [win]
    call    XDestroyWindow

    mov     rdi, [dis]
    call    XCloseDisplay

    xor     rdi, rdi
    call    exit

    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

the error seems to be coming from the `XCloseDisplay` function call

I have tried looking at my initialization of the window but I get no errors from there
when I comment out the `call XCloseDisplay`  I don't get the error.

I tried just commenting it out and ignoring it but got the same error trying to use `XNextEvent`

(also I am a bit of a noob at assembly so it may be a dumb thing I overlooked)

Comment: How have you defined `win`, `gc` and `dis`. Your question mention s`XCloseWindow`, did you mean `XDestroyWindow`? Just as a headup (and I say this without knowing what is at these memory locations), but the instruction `mov rdi, [dis]` will move the 8 byte value at memory address `dis` to RDI. `mov rsi, [gc]` and `mov rsi, [win]` I mention this because it is unclear if you want the address or the value at that address moved. It is preferable to create a [mcve] so we can try out a complete example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: sorry I meant to say 'XCloseDisplay' which was the bit that confused me, Also 'win' and 'gc'  are declared in .BSS and dis holds the pointer to the display struct returned by 'XOpenDisplay'

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just had passed the display into the window parameter of `XSetStandardProperties` in my initialization, but I only got the error when I tried to close the display.